# Webapp running in Jetty but not in Tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jetty, jstl, tomcat7

I made a Spring MVC webapp in which I used JSTL tags. I launched it by Gradle and it worked perfectly fine:

> gradle jettyRunWar

However, when I used the same WAR file with my Tomcat, I got error:

> The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application.

Using stackoverflow, I was able to fix. Problem was in my build.gradle file where I didn't specify the JSTL dependencies. I fixed that and I was able to run my webapp in Tomcat as well.

My question is why Jetty was able to run this app when Tomcat wasn't. How could I have avoided this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using JSTL Taglibs**

The JavaServer Pages Standlard Tag Library (`JSTL`) is part of the Jetty distribution and is automatically put on the `classpath` when you select your flavour of `JSP`. It is also automatically on the `classpath` for the jetty maven plugin, which uses the Apache `JSP` engine as of jetty-9.2.
Embedding

If you are using jetty in an `embedded` scenario, and you need to use `JSTL`, then you must ensure that the JSTL jars are included on the container's `classpath` - that is the `classpath` that is the parent of the webapp's `classpath`. This is a restriction that arises from the Java EE specification.

The jars that you will include will depend on the flavour of JSP that you are using.

**Tomcat** has never included `JSTL`.

You should put the `jstl` and standard jars in `WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: Actually, the JSTL is only available on Jetty, **IF** you use JSP and have it configured for the glassfish jsp impl.  If you use the apache jsp impl then JSTL is not included.